# Files are missing on iPad build

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I have a strange problem. I have a .bundle, with a lot images in it. Now the problem, when I build it on my iPhone everything works, every image is there, but not on my iPad, some images are not there. I already tryed to clean xcode, delete the old app and reinstall it again, reboot my iPad, reboot my mac, clean the project data.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this strange issue?

***EDIT:***
Here is the image loading code: 
`UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icons.bundle/icon-default.png"];`

Comment: How are you determining that the images are not there on the iPad? Actual device or simulator?

Comment: is different targets for ipad/iphone ?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Not there means nil for me

Comment: @sage444 I only have 2 targets, one for the simulator and one for the iOS devices

Comment: please provide example of image name that not shows, and code that should load it

Comment: @sage444 Question has been updated

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: How to use images in custom bundle in Interface Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733565/ios-how-to-use-images-in-custom-bundle-in-interface-builder)

Comment: @MarcusAdams No, its not a dublicate, cause I know how to use images in .bundles and its not the interface builder and it is working on the iPhone, but not on the iPad

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I am using asserts now…